# How can I pass parameters using expo-router?

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

This is in my index.js file and I'm trying to pass the access token to the home screen so I can use it to fetch notifications.

```js
import { router } from "expo-router";

result = JSON.parse(result);

router.replace("Homescreen", { token: result.access_token });
```

and my Homescreen.js file

```js
import { Button, View, Text } from "react-native";

export default function Homescreen({ route }) {
  const { token } = route.params;
  console.log(token, );
    
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Homepage</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I am getting undefined for token, anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use params

```
//index.js
import { router } from "expo-router";
result = JSON.parse(result);

router.push({
   pathname: "Homescreen",
   params: {
     token: result.access_token
   }
})
```

.

```
//Homescreen.js
import { Button, View, Text } from "react-native";
import { useLocalSearchParams } from "expo-router";

export default function Homescreen() {
  const { token } = useLocalSearchParams();
  console.log(token, );

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Homepage</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Please refer to this page:

https://docs.expo.dev/router/reference/search-parameters/

Comment: please elaborate by explaining what these codes do?